# Aggretating Windows Event Viewer events

Tags: c#, windows, events, event-viewer

My boss is wanting to capture certain Windows Event Viewer events from desktops as they happen.  Obviously, this means putting something on each machine that would monitor & aggregate desired events to a single database.  I'm sure there are tools out there to do this, be he isn't really that interested in buying more "stuff".

I already know how I would do it, but I was interested in seeing how others might accomplish the same task.

- I should make clear that I want to continuously monitor the event logs remotely
- I would prefer a push-option over a pull-option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you do not need to install anything in the client machines.

Have a look at the event log classes of the .NET Framework, when you open an event log you can pass the remote machine name to the constructor; in this way you can see the events of all machines from a centralized location (server) where you need to deploy only one copy of your application.

Comment: Awesome, I never knew that...now I'm glad I asked.  Any specific examples?

Comment: Question: Does remote viewing hinder the remote client much?

Comment: Hi, don't know, never actually used it. ;-)